# AngularUI - Google Maps - map is undefined

Tags: google-maps, angularjs, angular-ui

I am trying to use GoogleMaps directive this way:

**Controller Methods**

```
$scope.myMarkers = [];

$scope.mapOptions = {
    center : new google.maps.LatLng(35.784, -78.670),
    zoom : 15,
    mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

$scope.addMarker = function($event) {
    $scope.myMarkers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map : $scope.myMap,
        position : $event.latLng
    }));
};
```

**UpdateLocation.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="marker in myMarkers" ui-map-marker="myMarkers[$index]" ui-event="{'map-click': 'openMarkerInfo(marker)'}"></div>

<div id="map_canvas" ui-map="myMap" class="map" ui-event="{'map-click': 'addMarker($event)'}" ui-options="mapOptions"></div>
```

The map is shown perfectly but in method `addMarker` I am getting an undefined when `$scope.myMap` is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have a new scope being created somewhere between your controller definition and the `ui-map` div and what's happening is that the 'myMap' property is being created on that scope and not on your controller's scope.

To avoid this kind of problems, provide the `ui-map` directive a proper model. For example:

Controller:

```
$scope.model = { myMap: undefined };
```

HTML:

```
<div id="map_canvas" ui-map="model.myMap" class="map" ui-event="{'map-click': 'addMarker($event)'}" ui-options="mapOptions"></div>
```

This will force the `ui-map` directive to store the map content inside `$scope.model.myMap` and due to the prototypically inheritance of the scopes, the `$scope.model` object will be available on child scopes but will always belong to the parent scope - your controller's scope.

Comment: That worked!! Thank you very much!! I've wasted a lot of time with this problem. But I don't understand where a new scope is created. I am using angular-ui as documentation says